# Change aesthetics in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am new to graphs in R. I am trying to construct a forest plot to compare Odds ratio and CI. However the code I got from a stckoverflow post seems to be more aesthetic then I need. Below is the sample of data, code and image. I am trying to remove all colour aestheticsand just need white background, black lines and different black shapes for odds points. and also can i put the unadjusted anaemia first rather than the default one that is in the given image.

Data

```html
lag pollute or  lcl ucl
Other Backward Caste    Unadjusted anaemia  1.32    0.9 1.93
Other Backward Caste    Adjusted anaemia    1.25    0.84    1.87
Schedule Caste  Unadjusted anaemia  1.66    1.09    2.51
Schedule Caste  Adjusted anaemia    1.4 0.9 2.19
Schedule Tribe  Unadjusted anaemia  2.3 1.34    3.93
Schedule Tribe  Adjusted anaemia    1.93    1.08    3.44
General Unadjusted anaemia  1   1   1
General Adjusted anaemia    1   1   1
```

R Code

```html
ggplot(dat, aes(x = pollute, y = or, ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl)) + geom_pointrange(aes(color=factor(lag)), position=position_dodge(width=0.3)) + 
  ylab("Odds ratio & 95% CI") + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1)) + scale_color_discrete(name = "") + xlab("")
```

[image: Output image]

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Something like this? `ggplot(dat, aes(x = factor(pollute, levels = c("Unadjusted anaemia", "Adjusted anaemia")), 
                y = or, ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl)) + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(shape = lag), position=position_dodge(width=0.3)) + 
  ylab("Odds ratio & 95% CI") + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1)) + 
  scale_color_discrete(name = "") +
  xlab("") + 
  theme_bw()`

Comment: Thanks shadow. Everything went as wanted just now there is a legend heading as "lag" which i don't want, any way to remove the legend heading? Thanks boss thanks again.

Comment: Just add `theme(legend.title=element_blank())`

Comment: Thank you boss. It did the job!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dat, aes(x = pollute, y = or, ymin = lcl, ymax = ucl)) + 
  geom_pointrange(aes(shape = lag), position=position_dodge(width=0.3)) +  
  ylab("Odds ratio & 95% CI") + 
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept = 1)) +
  scale_color_discrete(name = "") +  xlab("") +
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(fill = 'white'))
```